# Post and excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, substr

I have the following piece of code which outputs a long article:

`<?php the_content(); ?>`

I am trying to show only an excerpt of the article (the first 29 words), strip out the HTML and add a "...more" at the end.

```
<?php substr(the_content, 29) ?>
```

I have tried this but it has no effect on the length.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [the_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt)

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> //and you could check the doc how to set the length.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo substr(get_the_content(), 0, 29); ?>
```

[the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) prints the content and [get_the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) will get that.